# Some devices dont show the launcher icon

Tags: android

Some people that use my application are complaining that after the update, the launcher icon went missing so they can't start the game. I myself don't have that problem. All ic_launcher.png images are in the drawable maps and I didn't change them.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="wetenschappelijk.project"
 android:versionCode="36"
 android:versionName="3.0.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
     <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".GalgjeActivity" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity     
        android:name=".MenuActivity" 
        />
    <activity     
        android:name=".GameActivity" 
        />

    <activity     
        android:name="wetenschappelijk.project.Settings"
        />
    <activity     
        android:name="wetenschappelijk.project.Multiplayer"
        />
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    <meta-data android:value="a14ef899d6be24a" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is no icon name :ic_launcher..
at that time the there is default icon name :icon.png already there

**Edit:**
As I showed in your manifest file .
you didn't display API minimum version.
may be that is issue:

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Comment: I dont quit understand , So you say if the ic_launcher.png isnt there it will load a default image?

Comment: first tell me if they are using your apk file or your source code?
I will give you more brief regarding this.

Comment: They are using the apk file , they updated through the android market